# drawRoundRect dibuja el rectángulo más grande JAVA

Tags: java

tengo un problema en Java y esque quiero crear un rectángulo con esquinas redondeadas, y le limito el tamaño por medio de la ventana, para que sea más pequeño que esta y poder hacer una especie de margen o padding. El problema es que la momento de ejecutar el rectángulo es más grande que la ventana.

Mi código es el siguiente:

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WindowApp {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        int windowHeight, windowWidth;

        NewWindow window1 = new NewWindow();

        windowHeight = window1.getWindowHeight();
        windowWidth = window1.getWindowWidth();

        NewPanel myPanel = new NewPanel();
        myPanel.setWindowHeight(windowHeight);
        myPanel.setWindowWidth(windowWidth);
        window1.add(myPanel);

    }
}



class NewWindow extends JFrame{

    private final int windowHeight = 600;
    private final int windowWidth = 800;

    public NewWindow(){

        //Gets the toolkit device
        Toolkit myToolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        //Uses the toolkit for get the screen size
        Dimension myScreenSize = myToolkit.getScreenSize();

        int height = myScreenSize.height;
        int width = myScreenSize.width;


        setVisible(true);
        //setResizable(false);
        setBounds((width/2)-(windowWidth/2),(height/2)-(windowHeight/2), windowWidth, windowHeight);
        setTitle("Window app");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public int getWindowHeight(){
        return windowHeight;
    }

    public int getWindowWidth(){
        return windowWidth;
    }
}

class NewPanel extends JPanel{

    int windowHeight, windowWidth;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawString("This is my first window app!", 10, 20);
        g.drawRoundRect(10, 30, windowWidth-20, windowHeight-40, 10, 10);
    }

    public void setWindowHeight(int windowHeight){
        this.windowHeight = windowHeight;
    }

    public void setWindowWidth(int windowWidth){
        this.windowWidth = windowWidth;
    }
}
```

---

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!

Comment: Y cual es el problema, que no sabes hacerlo más pequeño que la ventana??
Corrige esta línea `g.drawRoundRect(10, 30, panelWidth-40, panelHeight-80, 10, 10);` Pues restarle más o menos según a conveniencia. O incluso en el método main cuando llamas a los respectivos métodos.

Comment: Si se hacerlo más pequeño que la ventana. Es solo que si mi frame mide 250x250 yo hago mi cuadrado con menos pixeles que el frame y aún así es más grande.